# Smooth swiping in jQuery Mobile like iOS swiping

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to jQuery Mobile, and I am trying to replicate a native iOS app.

The problem I am facing is the that I cannot find a way to smoothly swipe between pages which is common on iOS. In jQuery Mobile, it seems to register a swipe occurred and then swipes the page for you, but I like the feel of having the page follow your swipe.

In iOS, you could use a UIScrollView with page control, but it was also really easy to do yourself by listening to touch events in a UIView.

Are there any libraries/packages that will help me create smooth swiping transitions? If not, are there jQuery bindings to track where the finger is on screen as it moves, so I can move the page and create such a transition myself?

Thanks

Comment: Swipe.js has a really good api for tracking swipe gestures.